# Does ServiceStack.Redis support RediSearch?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis, redisearch

We currrently use ServiceStack for the majority of our APIs.  We have come across the need to implement RediSearch against one of our Redis instances.  Does ServiceStack.Redis support RediSearch?

I know StackExchange.Redis does with the NRediSearch library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't due to lack of demand, feel free to submit a feature request for it so we can measure demand at:

## https://servicestack.net/ideas

Answer (score 3):

NRediSearch is the best RediSearch client out there for .NET.

NRedisStack is in the works to extend for all Redis Stack modules on StackExchange.Redis:
https://github.com/redis/NRedisStack

RediSearch is not fully implemented yet, it is in progress (on the SearchCommands branch) so it will be available soon.